# Cómo está funcionando el método?

Tags: javascript

Encontré en una respuesta este código, que no entiendo mucho su manera de funcionar:

```js
Date.prototype.getWeekNumber = function () {
    var d = new Date(+this);  //Creamos un nuevo Date con la fecha de "this".
    d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);   //Nos aseguramos de limpiar la hora.
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4 - (d.getDay() || 7)); // Recorremos los días para asegurarnos de estar "dentro de la semana"
    //Finalmente, calculamos redondeando y ajustando por la naturaleza de los números en JS:
    return Math.ceil((((d - new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0, 1)) / 8.64e7) + 1) / 7);
};
```

Se supone que este código devuelve el número de semana, según la fecha especificada.

Mi problema es al entender el código, cabe mencionar, que **yo no lo comenté ni modifique**.

***Lo que entiendo es:***

Crea una *instancia* de la clase `Date` con `this` y lo transforma a número con el operador `+` ( ***que nosé para qué lo hace***)

Resetea la hora a `0 horas , 0 minutos , 0 segundos , 0 ms`, que TAMPOCO entiendo **para qué**

***Luego cambia el día con setDate(), siguiendo unas operaciones, que realmente NO entiendo***

**Finalmente** realiza otras operaciones redondeando al entero mayor o igual, con `Math.ceil`, realizando una serie de operaciones, que no entiendo. Por qué y cómo lo realiza?

> *Destaco que quiero saber cómo funciona, cuál es su razonamiento.*

Comment: Por favor revisa esta pregunta [https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2808/son-válidas-las-preguntas-del-tipo-explicadme-esto-o-no-entiendo-tal-cosa](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2808/), es un acuerdo en la comunidad que preguntas como esta deberían ser cerradas. Asegúrate que tu pregunta sea lo suficientemente clara y concreta para no caer en los supuestos que se mencionan. En mi opinión __debería ser cerrada__ (en la pregunta en Meta, puntos 1 y 3).

Comment: La diferencia es que yo sí he buscado en internet e investigado, no busco que nadie me realize ningún trabajo, de hecho pongo mucho tiempo en leer códigos, para entenderlos por mi cuenta, además esto es una pregunta de programación, bien concreta sobre un código específico.

Comment: ¿En qué respuesta encontraste el código? ¿En una de SOes?

Answer (score 2):

El `+this` provoca que se convierta el valor actual del objeto en entero(valor epoch de la fecha), y crear un nueva fecha igual a la actual para manipularla en el calculo, 
[Date tiene varios constructores](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), uno es con el epoch de una fecha.

`d.getDay()` retorna el día de la semana con valores de 0 a 6, [donde 0 iniciando en Doming](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp) en este algoritmo usa el estandar ISO donde domingo es 7 por lo cual lo corrige con la expresión `||7` ya que `0||7` retornara la primera expresión que [logre retornar true](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators), `0` no se considera true, diferente de `0` si.

En ISO 8601 se considera la primera semana del año aquella que tenga el 4 de enero.

La linea `d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);` se requiere con el fin de que al momento de que se obtenga el `epoch` en el calculo retorne días concluidos desde el primero de enero del mismo año de la fecha. Al dividirlo entre `8.64e7` se obtienen la cantidad de días transcurridos menos 1 por lo cual hay que sumárselo. `8.64e7` representa la cantidad de milisegundos de un día. al dividir los días entre 7 obtiene la semana del año pero se debe redondear para el siguiente entero ya que las semanas se cuentan iniciando en 1.